# Titanium: Open Privacy -> Location Services programmatically

Tags: ios8, titanium, titanium-mobile

the following code is able to successfully launch my **App's settings** programmatically (iOS 8) in Titanium:

```
var settingsURL = Ti.App.iOS.applicationOpenSettingsURL;
if (Ti.Platform.canOpenURL(settingsURL)) {
  Ti.Platform.openURL(settingsURL);
}
```

The problem is that if a user has turned off their Location Services inside the **Privacy page** he/she won't be allowed to change this inside the **App's settings**, requiring the user to go back into **Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services**. This is very bad for the user experience-wise.

I know it is possible to launch the **Privacy -> Location Services** directly, since many apps do, like: Hotel Tonight, Foursquare, Dojo, etc.

How to do this in Titanium?

My configs: SDK 3.5.1GA & iOS8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work you need to try to create a listener to Titanium.Geolocation, something like:

```
Titanium.Geolocation.addEventListener('location', locationCallback);
```

Keep in mind you need to do this even **withou**t checking that you have permission, this way iOS will prompt you to turn on location services **using an alert dialog** and thus you can be redirected directly to **Privacy->Location Services**.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no API available.
In iOS 8 you can open setting but not Location setting directly
there was some url schemes to open setting functionality, example

```
 Ti.Platform.openURL('prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES');
```

but apple removed this from iOS 5.1. So it will not work on 5.1 and greater.

Comment: Although this is also correct (since you say there is no API) there IS a way to do this, and I figured it out. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @LucasA can you share your solution?

Comment: @RodionMamin I did, check the answer below.. Did that not work for you?

Comment: Is there no alternative to `Ti.Platform.openURL('prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES');` for newer versions of iOS. I know it's possible as the "Maps" app does it